# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'credential') Firebase Auth ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to confirm the user password again before the user tries to change the password.

Currently, my Firebase Auth project is configured in Firebase.js and is exported correctly

```
//appConfig = ...(all the configurations here)
const app = firebase.initializeApp(appConfig);

const projectAuth = app.auth()

export { projectAuth }
```

And in my PasswordManager.js, I use that exported projectAuth:

```
import { projectAuth } from "../firebase";

        const authenticateCurrentPassword = async (currentPassword) => {

        try {
            const cred = projectAuth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(
                projectAuth.currentUser.email, currentPassword);
            projectAuth.reauthenticateWithCredentials(cred)
            await projectAuth.reauthenticateAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(cred);
            dispatchIfNotCancelled( {type: 'AUTHENTICATED'})
            return true
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
            dispatchIfNotCancelled( {type: 'ERROR'})
        }
    }
```

On the line where I am trying to initialize the "cred", it gives me an error saying that credential doesn't exist:

> "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'credential')"

I know that credential is a function inside EmailAuthProvider.
btw: I'm using `"firebase": "^7.24.0"`, if that does any help.

Comment: `EmailAuthProvider` is a static property on `firebase.auth`, not on your `Auth` instance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider is not a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64347466/283366) (I'd close this as a duplicate but your bounty prevents that)

Comment: How does Firebase know it then? My Auth instance initializes with the app configurations that firebase gave me. But the static property is not initialized with anything. How does it connect with my database?

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're asking, sorry. The static [credential()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider#static-credential) method just takes your parameters and returns an [AuthCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.AuthCredential) instance. Whatever its doing internally, it doesn't need access to your database

Comment: So just like in the duplicate I linked, you want `const cred = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(projectAuth.currentUser.email, currentPassword)`

Comment: Ah right. I see. I can then use the credentials in my instance.

Answer (score 2):

this is what worked for me mind you am using angular 13 with angular/fire 7.2

i imported `EmailAuthProvider` direcly from `'firebase/auth'`

so my code looked like `const credentials = EmailAuthProvider.credential(user.email, password.old);`

i hope this helps